# Need help understanding this proof about Gelfand spectrum

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Consider the following theorem:

Let $A$ be a complex non-unital commutative Banach algebra and let $\Omega (A)$ denote its Gelfand spectrum / character space. Then $\Omega (A)$ is locally compact.

I don't understand the following proof:

It is easy to check that $\Omega (A) \cup \{0\}$ is weak star closed in the closed unit ball of $A^\ast$. Since the closed unit ball is weak star compact, $\Omega (A) \cup \{0\}$ is weak star compact and therefore $\Omega (A)$ is locally compact.

First of all, why do we need to consider $\Omega (A) \color{red}{\cup \{0\}}$ if we want to show that $\Omega(A)$ is locally compact? The other step I don't understand is: how does it follow from $\Omega (A) \cup \{0\}$ is weak star compact that $\Omega (A) $ is locally compact? Is it true that a compact space minus one point is locally compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not *need* to consider $\Omega(A)\cup \{0\}$, but it makes things easier, since that is a compact (Hausdorff, if that isn't part of your definition of compact) space.

Every open subspace of a compact (Hausdorff) space is locally compact, and since the weak* topology is Hausdorff, singletons are closed, whence

$$\Omega(A) = (\Omega(A)\cup \{0\}) \setminus \{0\}$$

is seen to be locally compact as an open subspace of the compact space $\Omega(A)\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you but now we only have $\Omega (A)$ is locally compact in $\Omega (A) \cup \{0\}$. Don't we need $\Omega (A)$ locally compact in $A^\ast$?

Comment: Being locally compact is a property of the topology of the space itself, it doesn't matter whether there is an ambient space at all, and if there is, how it looks like. Only, sometimes from the ambient space we get easy criteria to see the space we're interested in is locally compact. For example every open or closed subspace of a locally compact (Hausdorff) space is itself locally compact; thus every intersection of an open with a closed subspace too. And every compact space is locally compact. So here we have the situation that we can apply a simple criterion.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Now I'd like to ask you just one more (related) question: where in the proof in my question is it used that $A$ is commutative? It's not clear to me.

Comment: The commutativity of $A$ doesn't enter into this part. I guess the commutativity of $A$ is posited because the context is the Gelfand transform and the Gelfand-Naimark theorem, and for that you need the commutativity. We can consider the homomorphisms, and the space of homomorphisms also for non-commutative algebras, but they don't have as nice and interesting properties then as in the commutative case.

Comment: Great thank you very much!