# Spectrum of unital, commutative C star algebra

Tags: general-topology, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

According to the Wikipedia article on the Gelfand Represenetation (C* algebra section), the spectrum of a commutative C* algebra $A$ (the non-zero *homomorphisms $\phi : A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$)

i)is a locally compact Hausdorff space.

ii) and if $A$ is additionally unital (has an identity multiplicative element), the spectrum is compact.

The Hausdorff part is easy to prove, though I have been struggling with the compactness. I would appreciate if anyone can direct me to a proof of these statements.

I am pretty sure that it has to do with the fact that the spectrum space $\Phi$ is endowed with the weak* topology, and I think the elements of $\Phi$ (characters) are actually in $B_{A*}$. That is, you think of how the algebraic * homomorphisms are actually related to dual of A, since A is a Banach space. You can then se Banach Alaoglu- that $B_{A*}$ is weak-star compact.

However, I am struggling to see how to identify the spectrum with subsets of $A*$ that would allow me to exploit Banach Alaglu. I think it certainly isn't trivial, since A being unital changes the property from 'local compactness' to 'compactness' full stop.

Any links would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

In fact have just come across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746587/need-help-understanding-this-proof-about-gelfand-spectrum) which does the local compactness part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters are linear maps $A\to\mathbb C$. Being $*$-homomorphisms they are positive (since $\phi(a^*a)=|\phi(a)|^2\geq0$), so they are in $A^*$. Therefore one considers the weak$^*$ topology given by $A$.

Also from being $*$-homeomorphisms, you get that $\|\phi\|=1$ for all $\phi$. So they live in the closed unit ball of $A^*$, which is weak$^*$-compact by Banach-Alaoglu. Thus the closure of the set of characters is compact.

When $A$ is unital, the set of characters is closed; so compact. This is easy to see: a limit of $*$-homomorphisms is a $*$-homomorphism. When $A$ is not unital, the set is not closed because $0$ is in the closure.